# Will crossing out my ex-wife's name cause problems using my checks?

Tags: united-states, check, divorce

My ex-wife is no longer on my checking account, but I have still been using the checks with no problem.  Her name is written below mine.  I want to know if I take a marker and black out her name will the bank think something is fishy and deny it?  Doesn't really seem like an important part of the check.  Yes, I know I could just keep doing what works until the checks are used up, but in this case I would like to marker her name out.

Comment: Can you add country tag

Comment: I'm guessing US just by the way OP spelled "check".

Comment: My wife sticks updated return address labels over the old info in the corner, and I've seen plenty of crossed out phone numbers/addresses, or updated last names for someone who got married, it's no issue to update info on a check.

Comment: For what it's worth, when I got checks, I had them made with only my name on the top.  No address or phone number or anything.  I knew I would move, and I only use like 10 checks a year so made them as generic as possible.  The bank only cares about the numbers on the bottom... I've never had an issue.

Comment: People still use checks?  ;)

Comment: Yes, US and US territories.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Blimey, I don't think I've seen a cheque since the 90s!

Comment: Can't you just ask for a new chequebook?

Comment: Bad idea to keep the old checking account open, for very many reasons. Are her name and SSN still on the acct? And it's likely being reported to both of your credit records, even if she no longer has access to it. Also, what if someone issued a check/ refund/ invoice/receipt/ tax form/etc. addressed to both of you, following what's written on your check.

Comment: @Joe: in the US, the IRS and many govt agencies (federal, state and local) still use checks. Certainly, if they offer CC transactions at all, there will be an unpleasant 'convenience fee' and/or commission.

Comment: Sorry, I left out the /s ;)

Comment: @Joe: they are still the most efficient way for several things. In private transactions it is better than an electronic transfer because it leaves me with a clear proof of the payment (I can save a pdf image of the cheque from my online banking), while there is nothing like that with an electronic transfer. Also, there is still not a good substitute, for individuals, for a series of postdated cheques.

Comment: I really need to work on my sarcasm sign...

Comment: @Joe you'd think the winkey face was enough...

Answer (score 60):

If it were me, I would get a new checking account at potentially a new bank, but certainly with a new account number.

As Nathan said, there is no need for you to cross her name off the check, but potentially, she could use those checks, or have new checks printed to use.  Having her name on the check makes it seem like she is a legitimate signer on the account.

In the end you can fight and possibly win with your bank that they should not have accepted a check signed by her as payment, but why bother?  Also you will potentially alienate any merchant that accepts a check by her.  It is a total mess that can be relatively easily solved with very little money ($25-$40 for check reprinting) proactively.

Close the account, shred any existing checks, and move on.   Heck you can actually make money by doing this and receiving a bonus.  Check Nerd Wallet for current bank promotions.

Comment: +1 for closing this account and opening a new one. It's a cheap way to ensure there are no lingering issues like automatic payments you forgot to cancel that you no longer need. The printed name on the check is probably a non-issue.

Comment: if she is not on the account anymore, I don't think she can have new checks printed, though. (but she still could have remaining checks on that account)

Comment: so he should shred the checks only as they exit the checkbook? What about the remaining checks? (sorry Pete, too small a typo to edit).

Comment: Not sure how I feel about the NerdWallet promo at the end of the answer.

Comment: @njzk2 She most certainly could have checks printed.  Check printing companies do little to (usually) no verification that you actually have the right to ask for the check to be printed.

Comment: @Joe isn't your bank supposed to print your checks?

Comment: @njzk2 There are LOADS of third party check printers.  https://www.google.com/#q=custom+checks In fact, your bank probably contracts to one of them.

Comment: @quid wow, that just makes me hate checks even more...

Comment: Yep, I have never had a bank that handled checks after the first 25 or whatever.  Deposit slips sometimes, but not checks.

Comment: I don't understand this answer's objections. The threat it seems to highlight is that the ex wife would print new checks and use them. How is that threat related to either the existence or OP's use of the checks he already has? It seems to me that threat merely depends on 1) his wife knowing his account number, and 2) the bank making good on a check printed and signed by someone not on the account. In that case, I don't see how his wife is any different than, say, some contractor he decides to pay with a check (and reveal his account number to).

Comment: In other words, it seems like the real argument is that he should make sure his ex wife doesn't know his account number in case she decides to print new checks and commit fraud with them. But that threat is unrelated to what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Just beware of the effect on your credit score of closing your oldest-standing account, esp. if it was the only one on your credit history showing a long record of mortgage/loan payments.

Comment: @smci Checking accounts have no bearing on one's credit score, at least in the United States, where the asker appears to be from.

Comment: How will the asker alienate merchants if his ex-wife fraudulently uses checks from their formerly joint account to pay for things? Isn't that his ex-wife alienating the merchant?

Comment: Good point, what matters is the signers on the bank account, at our bank that's a physical card you must sign.   Honestly if the numbers on the bottom of the check jibe, they could have Vladimir Putin, Kremlin, Russia printed as the name and address on the checks, and nobody would care except small businesses who might actually eyeball that stuff.

Comment: @MikeHaskel, The idea is to remove potential human error, ex-wife might have an old checkbook and use it accidentally. To your point, any stranger can have checks made to match your account. Even though the ex-wife is removed from the account there are a number of mistakes that can occur and cause just as much trouble as a malicious fraudster. Cutting off the account has little actual cost, renders existing checks useless, and creates a clean history where there was never an additional signer and ex-wife was never named on the account. These risks may be small but the costs are small as well.

Comment: @DavidRicherby my wife's ex-husband was the only one on a car loan and it took *years* for her to get them to stop calling her for payment.

Comment: @WayneWerner Well, that's annoying but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with my comment.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Just because someone else is actually responsible for a thing, the fact that you're related can cause you problems if someone uses your name.

Answer (score 9):

If it doesn't seem that important, why bother blacking the name out? For the effort, it might cost you less in your time to have the checks reprinted.

There's no way to know what all banks would do with a check that has a name crossed out, but most would ignore it. Most checks are processed automatically. Signatures are not verified, post-dated checks can usually still be deposited. Occasionally you'll have a bank or merchant reject a check, but don't expect that to be the norm.

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, 20 years ago I had a huge box of sheet-feed checks (3 or 4 per sheet) - After the divorce I kept the account, then ran the remaining checks through a Word doc that tidily blacked out the ex's name.  Never had a hitch, glitch, or rejected check.

Comment: Your profile now has 'divorce' listed as a top tag :(

Comment: Except 20 years ago 95+% of your checks went to large  institutions most people now e-pay, and those are the folks that don't inspect much.   Nowadays my rare paper checks go to small outfits who would be more likely to eyeball.